# Placing text beside the navigation links

Tags: html

I have used float:left; to set my navigation links to the left of the webpage, however when I place text in the first four p tags the text is next to it but the fifth p tag goes underneath the navigation links rather than next to it. Why is that?

```css
  h1{
  color:orange;
}
body{
  background-color:white;
}

nav{    
  padding:0px;  
  margin-right:10px;
  float:left;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
nav ul a{
  color:green;  
}
nav a:hover{
  color:orange;
}
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
p{
  margin:0px;

}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center">Welcome</h1>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <a href = "homePage.html"> Home </a><br>
    <a href = "homePage.html"> Home </a><br>
    <a href = "homePage.html"> Home </a><br>
    <a href = "homePage.html"> Home </a><br>
  </ul>
</nav>


<p>testing</p>
<p>testing </p>
<p>testing </p>
<p>testing </p>
<p>testing </p>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're trying to achieve ?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title> practice </title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    h1{
        color:orange;
    }
    body{
        background-color:white;
    }
    
    nav{    
        padding:0px;    
        margin-right:10px;
        float:left;
    }

    nav a{
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    nav ul a{
        color:green;    
    }
    nav a:hover{
        color:orange;
    }
    ul{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    p{
        margin:0px;

    }
    
    
</style>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Welcome</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href = "homePage.html"> Home </a><p>Test</p><br>
            <a href = "homePage.html"> Home </a><p>Test><br>
            <a href = "homePage.html"> Home </a><p>Test</p><br>
            <a href = "homePage.html"> Home </a></p>Test<br>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    

</body>
</html>
```

I used this so many times.Hope i was helpful.

Comment: You didn't answer the question and your HTML is not valid